# Can a static method in a derived class call a protected constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, static, constructor, compiler-errors, protected

This code works with clang but g++ says:

> error: ‘A::A()’ is protected

```
class A
{
protected:
    A() {}
};

class B : public A
{
    static A f() { return A(); } // GCC claims this is an error
};
```

Which compiler is right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

g++ is right.

The C++ Standard §11.5/1 says that "<...> the access must be through a pointer to, reference to, or object of the *derived* class itself <...>". In case of constructors, this means that `B` is allowed to call the protected constructor of `A` only in order to construct its own base subobject.

Check [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8033) related issue in g++. It was closed as not a bug.

Comment: +1 As for the rationale, `protected` provides access to the `A` subobject inside `B`, not to *any* `A`. Another example would be `struct C : A { static void break_invariants( B& b ) { b.protected_member_from_A = 5; } };`, which could *potentially* break the invariants held in `B`.

Comment: David: it's interesting that you say that, because GCC *does* allow accessing (modifying) protected static data members of the base class from a static method in the derived class.  Do you think *that* is a bug in GCC then?

Comment: @Kirill: does that part of the standard apply only to constructors?  Because it seems that normal named methods and data members can be accessed in a similar way under GCC.

Comment: @John Zwinck, no, it's not only about constructors. Probably you use static members or you use normal named methods via *this* (implicitly).